# Redirect Loop, Faraway so Close

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically I need to let through requests to a specific path:

`https://domainfoo.com/my-app?param1=ABC&paramY=123`

Anything else, let's say, 
`https://domainfoo.com/aboutus`

I need it redirected to
`https://moodomain.io/aboutus`

I need this last part to be generic.

So Far I have this two rules:

To address the first requirement:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainfoo.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my\-app
RewriteRule ^(my\-app)$ https://domainfoo.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Then as a second rule (if first rule is matched (the `L`) should redirect and stop right? The thing is apparently it doesn't and then goes into the second rule:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainfoo.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainfoo.com$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my\-app$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://moodomain.io/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I have been dealing for hours with a looped redirect.

Ideas?

Comment: Your rules look ok. If you are getting redirect loop error on the destination domain then check your htaccess file on that domain.

Comment: Why would you need rewrite rules to... not rewrite or redirect? Basically, your first set of rules redirect to the same domain without modifying the request uri over an over again.

Comment: I need to take the visitor back to the "original domain" afterwards. The flow is, if they hit a specific path, I forward them to a different domain, the visitor does its interaction on that "different domain", any other path than that one on the "different domain" should be redirected to the "original domain"

Comment: Just read your first set of rules again. If domain starts with `domainfoo.com` and the path starts with `/my-app` then rewrite `/my-app` to `https://domainfoo.com/my-app` ($1 is `my-app` in that case). Guess what happens after you get redirected? The same rule applies because you didn't move at all.

Answer (score 1):

You first rule codes the rewriting loop, since you implemented an external redirection where none is required at all. Here is a simplified version:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainfoo\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?my-app$ - [END]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainfoo\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://moodomain.io/$1 [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

And if you need to redirect clients "back" to the first domain, as you later stated in the comments to the question, then add an explicit redirection for that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domainfoo\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?my-app$ https://domainfoo.com/my-app [R=301]
```